# Double forward slashes disappearing in mechanize

Tags: python, url, flask, mechanize, slash

I'm getting strange problems opening URLs with mechanize in Python. For some reason the double forward slashes in my URL are being replaced with a single forward slash.

I'm running

```
r = br.open(u"http://reddit.com")
```

and I'm getting URLError: no host given, because mechanize is receiving the url parameter as

```
u"http:/reddit.com"
```

according to the error logs I'm getting:

```
 /services/http/users/a/agora/howmanygiven/howmanyapp/howmany.py in countInPage(url=u'http:/reddit.com', s='word')
=>   14         r = br.open(u"http://reddit.com")
     15         html = r.read()
     16 
 /home/a/ag/agora/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mechanize/_mechanize.py in open(self=<mechanize._mechanize.Browser instance>, 
url=u'http:/reddit.com', data=None, timeout=<object object>)
=>  203         return self._mech_open(url, data, timeout=timeout)
    204 
    205     def _mech_open(self, url, data=None, update_history=True, visit=None,
```

Oddly enough the code works when I run it locally on my machine, but dies when it runs through flask on the server I'm hosting on. Any ideas?

Comment: May be different versions of mechanize?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, switched where I was hosting it. Seemed to be some strange error related to caching and running old python code from probably old pyc files. I've moved to a better hosting solution and have had no issues.